# Meta tag theme-color status bar icons color change

Tags: html, colors, statusbar, meta-tags

I want to add the meta tag to change the toolbar color to my website.

I have already added `<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">`, It is working fine for me.

But I want to change the status bar icon color(should be white), **it is by default black.** 
I want to handle same as youtube is handling.

**My website**

[image]

**Youtube**
[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Jesse still not found.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for apple

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">`

from https://medium.com/appscope/changing-the-ios-status-bar-of-your-progressive-web-app-9fc8fbe8e6ab